# Centralizar span na div usando flexbox

Tags: css, css3

Estou usando `positions` para usar o `top` e o `left` mas mesmo assim não fica coreto.

**CSS**:

```
span.vertical {
    writing-mode: vertical-lr;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    height: 200px;
}
span.comum {
    width: 100%;    
}
div.cabecalhoVertical{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    border: .1px rgb(0,0,0) solid;
}
div.cabecalhoVertical div {
    border-right: .1px rgb(0,0,0) solid;
    height: 100%;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
div.cabecalhoVertical div span {
    display: block;
    text-align: center; 
    font-weight: bolder;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div class='cabecalhoVertical'>
    <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'   >Nome do Gcéu </span></div>
    <div style='width:100px;'><span class='vertical'>Supervisor</span></div>
    <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'   >Líder</span></div>
    <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Houve Supervisão?</span></div>
    <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Houve dia de Jejum?</span></div>
    <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Houve dia de Evangedismo?</span></div>
    <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Membros Compromissados</span></div>
    <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Visitantes</span></div>
    <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Crianças de 0 à 12 anos</span></div>
    <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Total de presentes</span></div>
    <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Ofertas</span></div>                    
    <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Disicpulados</span></div>                    
    <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Número de decisões</span></div>                    
</div>
```

Ficou correto mas não consegui **centralizar** o texto (`span`) na `div` em uma das posições.

**Resultado**:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Tentei com o **CSS** abaixo usando o `postion` mas não ficou bom,

```
span.vertical {
    writing-mode: vertical-lr;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    height: 200px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -25%;
}
span.comum {
    width: 100%;    
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -100px;
}
div.cabecalhoVertical{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    border: .1px rgb(0,0,0) solid;
}
div.cabecalhoVertical div {
    position: relative;
    border-right: .1px rgb(0,0,0) solid;
    height: 100%;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
div.cabecalhoVertical div span {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;    
    font-weight: bolder;
}
```

O **objetivo** é **centralizar** o `span` tanto na **vertical** quanto na **horizontal**,
Tanto nos `spans` que estão virados quanto nos que não estão.
**Resultado**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sobre os itens que estão na horizontal, basta vc remover o `margin-top: -100` que vc colocou e já resolve.

Sobre os que estão na vertical tire o `margin-left: -25%` e coloque `translateX(50%)` junto com o `rotate`. *Ou se quiser fazer um pequeno ajuste ótico caso achei que não ficou 100% alinhado ai vc pode usar o `margin-left` mesmo, mas com 3 ou 4px de ajuste apenas além o `translateX`.*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja o resultado

```css
span.vertical {
    writing-mode: vertical-lr;
    transform: rotate(180deg) translateX(50%);
    height: 200px;
    left: 50%;
    /* margin-left: -25%; */
}
span.comum {
    width: 100%;    
    top: 50%;
    /* margin-top: -100px; */
}
div.cabecalhoVertical{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    border: .1px rgb(0,0,0) solid;
}
div.cabecalhoVertical div {
    position: relative;
    border-right: .1px rgb(0,0,0) solid;
    height: 100%;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
div.cabecalhoVertical div span {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;    
    font-weight: bolder;
}
```

```html
<div class='cabecalhoVertical'>
    <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'   >Nome do Gcéu </span></div>
    <div style='width:100px;'><span class='vertical'>Supervisor</span></div>
    <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'   >Líder</span></div>
    <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Houve Supervisão?</span></div>
    <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Houve dia de Jejum?</span></div>
    <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Houve dia de Evangedismo?</span></div>
    <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Membros Compromissados</span></div>
    <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Visitantes</span></div>
    <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Crianças de 0 à 12 anos</span></div>
    <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Total de presentes</span></div>
    <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Ofertas</span></div>                    
    <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Disicpulados</span></div>                    
    <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Número de decisões</span></div>                    
</div>
```

Comment: Ok. Mas ainda tem um problema nessa abordagem: Olhe que Nome do Gcéu não ficou exatamente centralizado. E, como ficaria o caso de que esse nome fosse por exemplo: Nome do Gcéu onde se encontra o ...: Bom, isso não caberia em uma só linha, o que iria dar problema. Entende? Para os verticais, o translateX resolveu. Tentei TranslateY no horizontal mas percebi que não tudo são flores. KKK

Comment: @CarlosRocha acho que por todas as perguntas e respostas que vc ja teve aqui no site esses tipos de ajuste finos vc já daria conta de fazer sozinho ao meu ver, nem tudo são flores, de fato, mas sei que se vc tentar vc resolve. O papel das respostas aqui eh te ajudar a crescer, e não fazer 100% do seu trabalho, ou prever do nada os problemas que vc tem ai e não mencionou quando fez a pergunta primeiramente. Com tudo que eu e o Sam já te respondemos não eh possível que vc não consiga fazer esse tipo de ajuste por conta própria. Vc tbm tem que fazer a sua parte ;)

Comment: Entendi. Então segundo a sua percepção eu não tentei aqui fazer isso? Eu tentei até com align-itens e não funcionou. N]ao sou do tipo que não tenta. Mas mesmo assim agradeço o seu esforço já feto e vou aceitar a sua resposta como aceita! É que aqui, não há um espaço próprio para mostrar as tentativas que fiz senão na pergunta. Estou seguindo por esse video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dbVQqcV9iEc, mas quando tento usar o alig-itens ele simplemente não funciona

Comment: @CarlosRocha o que to falando eh que com as técnicas abordadas nas outras respostas vc já conseguiria resolver isso, o align itens so alinha o filho se o pai tbm tiver display flex. Se vc acha que a resposta resolveu eh legal, mas se acha que ainda não esta da forma que gostaria não precisa preocupar em aceitar, pode aparecer mais alguém disposto a te ajudar com algo mais próximo do que vc precisa, a gente não responde só pelos pontos, e perguntas abertas não aceitas atrapalham o site. A intenção aqui eh ajudar a comunidade, os pontos são consequência. Abs

Comment: Obrigado, mas acho que estou meio perdido aqui. Tenho uma experiencia melhor em Back e apanho muito em css. Estou achando que aquele position: abasoluto está sendo o vilão. Vou tentar de outra forma

Comment: @CarlosRocha eu To na rua agora mas logo mais vejo se consigo melhorar algo pra vc

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado pelo apoio. Vou aguardar

Answer (score 1):

Consegui:

```css
span.vertical {
 writing-mode: vertical-lr;
 transform: rotate(180deg);
}
span.comum {  

}
div.cabecalhoVertical{
 display: flex;
 height: 200px;
 border: .1px rgb(0,0,0) solid;

}
div.cabecalhoVertical div {
 display: flex;
 flex-grow: 1;
 border-right: .1px rgb(0,0,0) solid;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
}
div.cabecalhoVertical div span {
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: bolder;
}
```

```html
<div class='cabecalhoVertical'>
 <div style='width:215px;'><span class='comum'   >Nome do Gcéu </span></div>
 <div style='width:215px;'><span class='vertical'>Supervisor</span></div>
 <div style='width:215px;'><span class='comum'   >Líder</span></div>
 <div style='width:035px;'><span class='vertical'>Houve Supervisão?</span></div>
 <div style='width:035px;'><span class='vertical'>Houve dia de Jejum?</span></div>
 <div style='width:035px;'><span class='vertical'>Houve dia de Evangedismo?</span></div>
 <div style='width:035px;'><span class='vertical'>Membros Compromissados</span></div>
 <div style='width:035px;'><span class='vertical'>Visitantes</span></div>
 <div style='width:035px;'><span class='vertical'>Crianças de 0 à 12 anos</span></div>
 <div style='width:035px;'><span class='vertical'>Total de presentes</span></div>
 <div style='width:035px;'><span class='vertical'>Ofertas</span></div>     
 <div style='width:035px;'><span class='vertical'>Disicpulados</span></div>     
 <div style='width:035px;'><span class='vertical'>Número de decisões</span></div>   
</div>
```

Agora é tentar com **UL**

Comment: Estranho! Com UL ao invéz de DIV aparece uma espécie de célula ocuta a mais no canto equerdo empurrando o "Nome do Gceu" para a direita. O que será que é?

Comment: Cara não vou saber dizer pq tem esse comportamento, mas legal que resolveu!

Comment: é, o objetivo é fazer com a menor quantidade de linhas

Comment: para resolver o problema com a UL, basta retirar o padding padrão antes da primeira LI qe é de 40px fazendo padding:0